# django Q objects ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build Q objects dynamically. This is my code:

```
class StudentiRicerche(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = StudentiLista

    def get_queryset(self):

        query_params = self.request.query_params

        q_objects = Q()
        for k, v in query_params.items():
            param = '{0}__icontains={1}'.format(k, v) # k and v are dynamic values
            q_objects &= Q(param)

        queryset = Studenti.objects.filter(q_objects) # Here i get an error
        return queryset
```

With this code I am getting a ValueError on the line where I use filter

I have also tried to use a list of Q objects insted of Q objects directly in this way:

```
class StudentiRicerche(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = StudentiLista

    def get_queryset(self):

        query_params = self.request.query_params
        q_list = []

        for k, v in query_params.items():
            param = '{0}__icontains={1}'.format(k, v)
            q_list.append(Q(param)) # Q with 'and' condition

        queryset = Studenti.objects.filter(*q_list) # here I get an error also
        return queryset
```

But here I am getting again the same error! Any idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify. You don't need use Q:

```
class StudentiRicerche(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = StudentiLista

    def get_queryset(self):

        query_params = self.request.query_params
        queryset = Studenti.objects.filter(**{'{}__icontains'.format(k):v for k,v in query_params.items() })
        return queryset
```

Explain:

1. Arguments of `.filter` and `Q()` is dictionary, not list
2. `.filter` and `Q()` use named-arguments, such as: `.filter(name__icontains='Ivan', email__icontains='mail.com')`
3. But you can use **kwargs: `.filter(**{'name__icontains':'Ivan', 'email__icontains': 'mail.com')`
4. For you example:  `.filter(**{'{}__icontains'.format(k):v for k,v in query_params.items() })`
5. If you want `Q()` dynamically you must use dictionary: `Q(**{'{}__icontains'.format(k):v for k,v in query_params.items() })`

and in addition

6. You can use combination of named-arguments and **kwargs, such as `.filter(is_active__isnull=False, **{'{}__icontains'.format(k):v for k,v in query_params.items() })`

Comment: I will check this out and I will make you know!! In fact I am seeing that I must pass **kwargs to filter :)